# Error: Maven installation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, m2e

In tried to install MAVEN Plugin in Eclipse:
Process is...

> In Eclipse3.5 version...
>
> Help-->InstallNewSoftware-->Add-->
>
> Name=Maven
>   URL=http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e -->ok

Then i got the below error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor 0.12.1.20110112-1712) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
    To: org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor [0.12.1.20110112-1712]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Maven Eclipse integration has completely moved to http://eclipse.org, try with new update URL, http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases However, there is no reason why Sonatype one will fail.

Answer (score 2):

As of Indigo release, there is no longer a separate Sonatype update side needed for M2E. M2E can be found in the pre-configured "Indigo" update site.

From within Eclipse, select the Help->Install New Software menu item. Select the "Indigo" update site.

After you select a site, it can take up to a minute before the software choices can be expanded in the table in this "Install" dialog. Once Eclipse has downloaded the software choices, select "M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse" under "General Purpose Tools".
Finish the installation and restart Eclipse.